# SQL: many to many resolution and intersection entities

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

With a many to many relationship, an intersection table is used to resolve this to two one-to-many relationships. My problem here is that I currently have 2 tables, "Playlist" and "song". Each song be present in many playlists, and each playlist can contain many songs. To resolve this add a third table, "songlog" to resolve the many to many.

I understand this much, however, when it comes to adding values into the database, I'm a tad confused. For example, how would I add some (e.g 4) songs into the playlist table, using the intersection table? Also, how would I then add the details of which songs are in which playlist?
Have I got this very wrong, is this a true many to many, or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

I'm very confused, so a clear and basic explanation of this area of design may help! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break down the problem a little bit.

You've got songs.

```
CREATE TABLE Songs
(
  SongID int,
  SongName varchar(50)
);
```

You've got playlist information. (Name of the playlist, who created it, blahwhatever).

```
CREATE TABLE PlaylistDef
(
  PlaylistID int,
  PlaylistName varchar(50)  
);
```

You've got songs who are in playlists. Songs can be in multiple playlists.

```
CREATE TABLE Playlist
(
  PlaylistID int,
  SongID int
);
```

Lets populate the tables:

```
INSERT INTO Songs
(SongID, SongName)
VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C'),
(4, 'D'),
(5, 'E');

INSERT INTO PlaylistDef
(PlaylistID, PlaylistName)
VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'b');


INSERT INTO Playlist
(PlaylistID, SongID)
VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(2, 5);
```

Then you can now run something like this to see a specific playlist.

```
SELECT * FROM Playlist WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE PlaylistID = 2
```

And it'll return this:

```
PLAYLISTID  SONGID
2           2
2           3
2           4
2           5
```

Does this help?

Comment: ok thanks! I think I was getting confused with adding multiple values to the playlist table! SO its possible to add multiple songs to the playlist table, i.e playlistdef (1) and playlistdef (2), as long as you specify they're both being added into playlist number 1 (for example)?

Comment: Say you own playlist 1 under your account. I own playlist 2 under my account. We don't own the songs, but we want to play a subset of the songs that exist.

I like song 1,2,4. You like song 2,4,5. We can setup our playlists as we like, and whenever our account says 'Play my playlist', it'll play Playlist 1 for me, or playlist 2 for you. I hope this clears it up a bit? Please re-ask if I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is an order of operation question: Codewise we must first add songs before they can add them to the PlayListSongs.  However from the users perspective we may allow them to add songs to lists at the same time we are updating the list.

```
PlayList (ID, Name)
1 My List 1
2 My List 2

Song (ID, Name)
1 Song A
2 Song B
3 Song C


PlayListSongs (PlayListID, SongID), (or what you called songLog)
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

When adding songs, you must first Add them to the songs table get an ID and then add the relationship to the playlist. From a user interface you could do this all at once for the user.  By allowing them to add songs to an existing playlist,  However, you MUST, under the covers, first add the list to the songs table, then add it to the playListSongs... illustration below.

Event - user adds a new song "Song D" to their PlayList "My List 1"

1. They interact with the UI entering in needed information
2. The application calls a procedure which first saves the song information to the song table. This  results in and entry "4 Song D"
3. The procedure captures the NEW ID created and uses it along with the currently selected playlist to put an entry in PlayListSongs (1,4)

Event - User just wants to add a bunch of songs
 1. We save the song information use enters into song table

Event - User wants to create a new playlist with songs
 1. We insert a new record in PlayList
 2. We allow user to select existing songs (this just results in entries
 3. we allow user to dynamically create new songs add to song table and automatically add to playlist selected.

Answer (score 0):

For your intersection tables you may have something like:

**songs**

```
id
title
artist
length
```

**playlists**

```
id
title
```

**playlists_songs**

```
song_id
playlist_id
order
```

For each **song** in your application there will be one row. For each **playlist** there will be one row. For the songs in any given playlist there will be multiple rows. Once you have rows for songs and playlists in their respective tables you can add songs to a playlist. To do so you need to insert a row into the **playlists_songs** table with the `song_id` (these will be different) and the `playlist_id` (these will be the same) for the adding operation. Additionally the table stores the order for the song in the playlist so that you can sort them later. The queries might look like:

```
INSERT INTO playlists_songs (song_id, playlist_id, order) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO playlists_songs (song_id, playlist_id, order) VALUES (2, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO playlists_songs (song_id, playlist_id, order) VALUES (3, 1, 3)
INSERT INTO playlists_songs (song_id, playlist_id, order) VALUES (4, 1, 4)
```

The above will add songs with id of 1, 2, 3, and 4 to the playlist with id of 1. To get the songs for playlist 1 you could then do something like:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM songs AS s
    INNER JOIN playlists_songs AS p 
        ON p.song_id = s.song_id
WHERE p.playlist_id = 1
ORDER BY p.order
```

Comment: ok thanks! I think I was getting confused with adding multiple values to the playlist table! SO its possible to add multiple songs  to the playlist table, i.e playlists_songs (1) and playlists_songs (2), as long as you specifiy they're both being added into playlist number 1 (for example)?

Comment: Yes, that table serves as the many-to-many mapping. Using it you can find out which songs are used in any given playlist. You can also do the reverse to find out which playlists a given song belongs to by asking for all the playlists with the song_id.